# How do I navigate to another screen by clicking on button in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

How do I make it so that it goes to ChatScreen when I click the "OK" button?

```
.alert(
    Text("enter chat screen"),
    isPresented: $showConfirmationPopup
) {
    Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) {}                    
    Button("OK") {
        print("enter screen tapped")
        // some operations
    }
} message: {
    Text("enter chat screen?")
}
```

I tried to wrap the "OK" button in `NavigationLink` but it didn't work. I tried to add `NavigationLink(destination: ChatScreen()) {}` under the ok button but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should replace the `Button` with a `NavigationLink`. And the view with the alert needs to be inside a `NavigationStack`.

Here is a standalone example to show it working:

```swift
struct ChatScreen: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("ChatScreen")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showConfirmationPopup = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Button("Show alert") {
                    showConfirmationPopup = true
                }
            }
            .alert(
                Text("enter chat screen"),
                isPresented: $showConfirmationPopup
            ) {
                Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) {

                }
                NavigationLink("OK") {
                    ChatScreen()
                }
            } message: {
                Text("enter chat screen?")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, Its not going to ChatScreen, its just dismissing the alert

Comment: Did you test the exact code I provided? Works for me on an iPhone 14 simulator running iOS 17.0 (Xcode 15.0.1). If you just tried to adapt the code, did you make sure that the view with the alert is inside a ```NavigationStack```?

Comment: Thank you very much Benzy, you are a brain saver. I forgot to put NavigationStack on top

Comment: Just one more thing, How do I do other operations (like calling a function) when clicking on "OK"

Comment: @DeepanshuKashyap You could add an ```.onAppear``` modifier to ```ChatScreen()```.  But if you need to run code before ```ChatSCreen``` is initialized then perhaps you don't want to be using a ```NavigationLink``` after all. You could investigate using a regular ```Button``` and then performing programmatic navigation instead. This would mean creating the ```NavigationStack``` with a ```path``` as init parameter. I would suggest making it the topic of a new question if you're not able to work it out.

Comment: will do, thanks a lot for help

Answer (score 2):

**@Benzy Neez answer is definitely easier**, but this would 1. be able to execute an action on tap of the button in the alert and 2. is suitable for programmatic navigation

You can use `NavigationLink` with the `isPresented` parameter, though it‘s deprecated. You could also use `.navigationDestination(for:` ..